# How to add a dimension to an array and fill up the new dimension with a set of same data

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, expand, dimension

I have two 1D-arrays. I need to expand the first array (a) with all lines from the second array (b) to create a new array that is a 1D-array merging the two arrays.

Example below to be clearer:

```
a = np.array(['x', 'y'])
b = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'])
# how to handle the above 1D-arrays to create the below array (c)?
c = np.array(['xa', 'xb', 'xc', 'ya', 'yb', 'yc'])
print(c)
```

The new array c would look like:

```
['xa' 'xb' 'xc' 'ya' 'yb' 'yc']
```

Of course, I can do it with loops, but I'm looking for a smarter code.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2 lists, a smart thing is to use a list comprehension:

```
In [234]: a = ['x', 'y']
     ...: b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
In [235]: [i+j for i in a for j in b]
Out[235]: ['xa', 'xb', 'xc', 'ya', 'yb', 'yc']
```

For arrays you can use `np.char.add` as shown in the other answers:

```
In [236]: A=np.array(a); B=np.array(b)
In [237]: np.char.add(A[:,None],B)
Out[237]: 
array([['xa', 'xb', 'xc'],
       ['ya', 'yb', 'yc']], dtype='<U2')
```

Timeit on such a small example has to viewed with caution.  Often times for lists are better for small examples, but don't scale nearly as well.  But I expect `np.char.add` will hurt the array scaling (the `np.char` functions just apply standard string methods to the array elements.).

```
In [238]: timeit np.char.add(A[:,None],B)
23.2 µs ± 57.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
In [239]: timeit [i+j for i in a for j in b]
1.55 µs ± 35.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

Specifying `object` dtype when making the arrays, we can use the `+` operator, and gain some speed:

```
In [240]: A=np.array(a,object); B=np.array(b,object)    
In [241]: A[:,None]+B
Out[241]: 
array([['xa', 'xb', 'xc'],
       ['ya', 'yb', 'yc']], dtype=object)    
In [242]: timeit A[:,None]+B
7.39 µs ± 76.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

For reference, adding two numeric arrays:

```
In [245]: %%timeit x=np.arange(2); y=np.arange(3)
     ...: x[:,None]+y
5.95 µs ± 8.71 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
In [246]: %%timeit x=np.arange(200); y=np.arange(300)
     ...: x[:,None]+y
100 µs ± 533 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

The 2nd case is 10_000 larger, but time increases only 20x.

Comment: Thank you for the solutions and the timeit, it helps a lot. I go for the [i+j for i in a for j in b] with a np.asarray in front as I want an array: np.asarray([i+j for i in a for j in b])

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy broadcasting:

```
>>> np.char.add(a[:, None], b).ravel()
array(['xa', 'xb', 'xc', 'ya', 'yb', 'yc'], dtype='<U2')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy `meshgrid` method and then Transpose `T`:

```py
np.array([x+y for x, y in np.array(np.meshgrid(a, b)).T.reshape(-1,2)])
```

**Result**

```py
array(['xa', 'xb', 'xc', 'ya', 'yb', 'yc'], dtype='<U2')
```

Answer (score 0):

keep it simple, use two looping structures

```
a = np.array(['x', 'y'])
b = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'])

def find_combination(a, b):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(len(b)):
            result.append(a[i] + b[j])
    return result


print(find_combination(a, b))
```